# Why "result was not a number" error even if script works correctly?

Tags: google-sheets, error-handling

this is the function I'm running in google sheets. It works properly and also worked in my sheet unti now, that, without a reason, I have "result was not a number" error. The script still works without error.

```
I'd past the code here but I have this error and I don't know what to do...
```

Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Here's how you can [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the draft and staring again. Add the " ``` " above and below where you want to add the code before pasting your code in between them.